# For Loop Only Executes First Object in a List

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to use the `Google Maps API` to loop up the ratings of two properties that I have to put into a list, but I am getting the result for the first property twice. Please help me to know what I'm missing.

**Here is the code:**

```
addresses = ['mall of america in bloomington', 'king of prussia mall']

for i in addresses:
    get_rating = gmaps.find_place(input=addresses, input_type = 'textquery', fields=['name', 'place_id', 'rating'])
    print(get_rating)
```

**Here is the result:**

```
{'candidates': [{'name': 'Mall of America®', 'place_id': 'ChIJLWE8OWwv9ocRayh4boDxxrM', 'rating': 4.6}], 'status': 'OK'}
{'candidates': [{'name': 'Mall of America®', 'place_id': 'ChIJLWE8OWwv9ocRayh4boDxxrM', 'rating': 4.6}], 'status': 'OK'}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with the details needed to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first statement of your loop:

```py
get_rating = gmaps.find_place(input=addresses, input_type = 'textquery', fields=['name', 'place_id', 'rating'])
```

you are using the list, `addresses`, as the input, when I believe you have meant to use `i`, the element in the list. The corrected code would be:

```py
addresses = ['mall of america in bloomington', 'king of prussia mall']

for i in addresses:
    get_rating = gmaps.find_place(input=i, input_type = 'textquery', fields=['name', 'place_id', 'rating'])
    print(get_rating)
```

To answer your comment about how to retrieve the values of the ratings:

It appears as thought the returned value is a dict value. In which case, you can iterate over it like any other dict:

```py
import json

addresses = ['mall of america in bloomington', 'king of prussia mall']
ratings = []

for i in addresses:
    get_rating = gmaps.find_place(input=i, input_type = 'textquery', fields=['name', 'place_id', 'rating'])
    for candidate in get_rating['candidates']:
        ratings.append(candidate['rating'])
```

It's up to you to figure out how to get the ratings values into a csv format, and to catch any edge cases that may arise, such as:

- What if the search returns no candidates?
- What if there is no "rating" value in the candidate result?
- What if the return type of `gmaps.find_place` is not `dict`?

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. Would you also know how I can extract the rating of the property into a CSV? I'm talking about the number 4.6 in this result.

{'candidates': [{'name': 'Mall of America®', 'place_id': 'ChIJLWE8OWwv9ocRayh4boDxxrM', 'rating': 4.6}], 'status': 'OK'}